# ArcMap 10.6.1 Identify Window blocked

Tags: arcgis-desktop, identify, arcgis-10.6

I am a new user of ArcGIS software. I used the *identify* tool to inspect a layer, but the window is blocked in the middle of the screen, with no possibility of shutting it down. I tried to close ArcMap and re-open it, but it resumes the last tools activated. I found no way to solve this issue but to uninstall and reinstall the whole software, but the problem eventually popped up again as soon as I had to use identify again. Now I am stuck. I did not find any previous post with this same problem, actually I only read about the opposite issue.

I am using ArcGIS 10.6.1 on a Windows 10 machine. Any tips?

Comment: Dear @Luke I am currently uninstalling again the software, hoping this does not happen again, but in case it will, I will post a screenshot. In any case, where would I be supposed to fine the file normal.mxt you mentioned?

Comment: I was guessing so, but in the meanwhile I had a few problem. I will return to you as soon as I re-install ArcMap (if the problem persists), and I'll post a screenshot of the issue. Thank you a lot for your advices.

Comment: https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Luke posted as a comment, I had to delete the normal.mxt file. 
It a can be found in both the following folders (windows user):

C:\Users\tgreco\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcMap\Templates
C:\Users\tgreco\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcCatalog

In order to visualize the normal.mxt file, you need to enable the visualization of the hidden objects and folders in your OS.
Once the file has been deleted (or renamed), simply restart windows, to make the change effective.

Best

PS: and thanks again to @Luke for the comments